# Question about getting URL backlinks optimized by UTM parameters and its affect on SEO

Tags: seo, backlinks, link-building, utm-parameters

I am starting to promote my blog posts on forums etc...
I have two these questions:

1. When I trying to get backlinks from forums or comments and contributing as a third person talking about our brand and website then he/she inserting our page's url on that location, normally it is good but never third person user uses UTM parameters on the url. 
   or maybe a gust post on other blogs.

Does google consider URL with UTM parameters as a black hat SEO efforts ?
As much as we try to get backlinks and promote our website pages on other websites, we need to track efficacy of our external backlinks to our websites and we need to use UTM.
I hope to explain my issue correctly.

2. What is your suggestion for structuring our UTM url for promoting our webpages include Blog posts on other website as a SEO backlinks?

my current structure is like below:

**UTM Meduim:** "refferal" or "Backlinks"

**Source:** "Joomla_forum" (target website we trying to get backlinks)

**UTM content:** "Joomla_tutorial" (Anchor text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does google consider URL with UTM parameters as a black hat SEO efforts ? As much as we try to get backlinks and promote our website pages on other websites, we need to track efficacy of our external backlinks to our websites and we need to use UTM. I hope to explain my issue correctly.

No, it is not considered as black hat technique, however it is good to use UTM parameters to track the source of traffic, whose efforts made so (medium), what was promoted(campaign) and the content.

Even Google suggest you to do so, such that you can measure your marketing efforts and its output.

> What is your suggestion for structuring our UTM url for promoting our webpages include Blog posts on other website as a SEO backlinks?

Here's my suggestion

```
utm_source=domain.com
utm_medium=yourname or companyname
utm_campaign=organicSEO or Traffic or GuestPost
utm_content=TitleOfPost or AnyInfomatoryText
```

Drawback of UTM parameter URLs:

- URL becomes lengthy, which looks suspicious to some people
- Some website doesn't allow you to do so, as they don't want promotional
  content

Mostly people out there use URL shortener like bit.ly to shorten the UTM URLs, even these platforms have their own analytics where from you can measure how many people clicked it and where from they were.